# KnockoutJS and async ajax call

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js, spservices

I am using SPServices and KnockoutJS to load some data on a page, specifically a list of projects and the number of tasks for each project.

I have simplified the example a bit but what I am having issues with is to get the value of the ajax call async. I solved it cheaply by using jQuery to bind the result instead of returning anything:

```
function ProjectModel(title, id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
        self.title = title;             
    self.tasks = ko.computed(function() {
              $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: true,
                webURL: "/projects/" + self.id,
                listName: "Tasks",
                CAMLQuery: // query..,              
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        $(".tasks-" + id).text($(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").length);  
                        }
              });       
        });
}
```

I had a look at these sites
[Async dependantobservables](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/asynchronous-dependent-observables)
[async computed observables](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/asynchronous-computed-observables-in-knockout-js/)

Is this the way to go?
Edit:

OK so some more code (have stripped out some stuff here):

```
function onGetProjectsCompleted(projects) {
    var projectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
    projectViewModel.init(projects);
    ko.applyBindings(projectViewModel);
}

function beforeLoadingProjects() {
    $(".loadingMessage").show();
}

function initProjectsView() {
    ProjectsRepository.getOpenProjects(beforeLoadingProjects, onGetProjectsCompleted);
}

function ProjectViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.openProjects = ko.observableArray();       

        self.init = function initProjectViewModel(projects) {
            $.each(projects, function() {
                self.openProjects.push(this);
            });

            });
        };
    }


    var ProjectsRepository = {
        getOpenProjects: function (beforeComplete, onComplete) {
            var options = {
                operation: "GetListItems",
                completefunc: function(xData, status) {
                    var projects = new Array();
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                        var item = $(this);
                        projects.push(new ProjectModel(
                            item.attr("ows_Title"), 
                            item.attr("ows_ProjectID")                      
                        ));
                    });
                    onComplete(projects);
                }
            };

            beforeComplete();
            $().SPServices(options);
        }
    };
```

Please note, I don't want to list the tasks for each project, I just want to have a property with the Number of tasks for each project, i.e. no array.

Thanks again.

Comment: to handle async javascript i would suggest looking at using promises. jQuery has promises, but I use Q.js as my prefered promises library.  https://github.com/kriskowal/q.  It makes using async calls much simpler.

Comment: Code in `completefunc` should be abstracted to a custom binding, its a anti pattern to have DOM dependencencies in the VM

Comment: Can I see how you are try into use ProjectModel? Also, what do you expect ProjectModel.tasks to be? An array of objects I assume?

Comment: Anders, hence I posted this.. because I wasn't sure how to solve it.

Comment: @PaulT. no array, just a value

Comment: Ok.  So 'tasks' should be a number indicating the number of tasks.  And you are ok with that being retrieved async, correct.  Meaning, that value (an observable) will not be set initially.  I'll try to post back a revised solution on this tomorrow.  On my phone right now.

Comment: Ok this is embarrassing but it has probably worked for some time. When I do console.log(self.tasks().length)  after the ajax call I always get 0 so stopped there. I just tried with keeping it but databind it like so <span data-bind="text: tasks().length"></span> and that worked fine

Comment: yep that will do it :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out... Sounds like you really need to read up on what synchronous and asynchronous is and understand the flow of your program. I changed my example below to have 'tasks' be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell how you are trying to use the class (Model) above, but @anders is correct: your model should not manipulate DOM element directly... That's what Knockout's view binding is for...

Try this (disclosure: I did not test this in a live environment):

### Model:

```
function ProjectModel(title, id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.title = title;
    self.tasks = ko.observable(0);


    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        webURL: "/projects/" + self.id,
        listName: "Tasks",
        CAMLQuery: // query..,              
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

            if (Status !== "success") {
                alert("failed to get tasks! Ajax call error.");
                return;
            }

            self.tasks(
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr('ItemCount')
            );

        }
    });
}
```

#### View:

```
<div id="mytemplate">
    <h2>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span> Project has 
        <span data-bind="text: tasks"></span> Tasks
    </h2>
</div>
```

#### Controller/Binding:

```
ko.applyBindings(
    new ProjectModel("your project title", "your project ID"),
    document.getElementById("mytemplate")
);
```

Try to use the above and see if you get output... The number of tasks will be initially zero, but if your tasks list is valid and tasks are there, then it will update itself once the query completes.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this, however, if I do console.log(self.tasks().length) at the end in completefunc I get the correct length but if I do it in the end of the ProjectModel I always get 0

Comment: @john-doe, That's expected... 
The SPServices call above is asynchronous... thus the array of tasks is not initially (right after you do a `new ProjectModel`) populated... Depending on what you are trying to do (_again: you were not clear there... see my original questions_) that might be ok... just take advantage of KO's ObservableArray's Events to trigger ccode when that array is populated... If, however, you do want that list populated as soon as a new instance of ProjectModel is instantiated, then change the SPServices `async` parameter above to `false`.
Did you try the full example above?

Comment: I did but can't get it to work. What's missing in your example is to first get the projects then the tasks. First I have to query one list in root site to get a list of projects, then I have to query another list for each project to get the number of tasks (in a subsite for each project). If I load all projects and tasks with async false then the screen is blank for 5-6s before all data is loaded. Hence I want to load all projects based on some conditions, list them on the screen and then fetch the tasks from a subsite for each project. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Spent too much time on this now, wonder if it's possible at all?

Comment: Sorry John.  There is something missing in explaining what you are trying to do.  The Model above should work async, but again: what are you trying to do with the data an how. I suggest you post the full code somewhere so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SPServices before, but I would start by separating the model from the ajax calls by creating a service object. then pass in the observable to be filled once the

Something like

```
var ajaxServices = (function(){
      return {
        getProjectTasks: getProjectTasks
      };
      function getProjectTasks(projectId, tasksObservable){
        $().SPServices({
          operation: "GetListItems",
          async: true,
          webURL: "/projects/" + projectId,
          listName: "Tasks",
          CAMLQuery: // query..,              
          CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
          completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          tasksObservable(xData);
        }); 
      }
    })();


function ProjectModel(title, id) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.title = title;             
  self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.getTasks = function (){
    ajaxServices.getProjectsTasks(sif.id, self.tasks);
  };    
}
```

Comment: so how do I actually fill self.tasks, self.getTasks isn't executed. I don't need an observableArray for a list of tasks, just an observable for the number of tasks a project has

Comment: calling self.getTasks can be called when ever you need it to.  if it has to be called when the project model is created then add `self.getTasks();` to the end of the project model.  Using an observable array to hold your tasks has many benefits, the main one being that when a task get added to the array, it will update the display automatically